# How to rotate object about x-axis

Tags: php, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to rotate some 3d objects about the x-axis (I don't need to rotate them on their center so no need to translate to 0,0,0 first then back to their original position). I've just written a quick php script to test it out on an obj file. I've checked out the Wikipedia page for matrix rotation and was pretty confident my code would work...

CreateXrotationMatrix takes an angle and creates the required rotation matrix from

```
      [1 0    0    ]
Rx(α)=[0 cosα -sinα]
      [0 sinα cosα ]

function CreateXrotationMatrix($alpha)
{
    $matrix = Array();
    $matrix[0] = 1;
    $matrix[1] = 0;
    $matrix[2] = 0;
    $matrix[3] = 0;
    $matrix[4] = cos($alpha);
    $matrix[5] = -sin($alpha);
    $matrix[6] = 0;
    $matrix[7] = sin($alpha);
    $matrix[8] = cos($alpha);

    return $matrix;
}
```

MultiplyMatrices then multiplies a 3x3 matrix by a given point

```
function MultiplyMatrices($rotationMatrix, $point)
{
    $returnMatrix = Array();
    $returnMatrix[0] = $rotationMatrix[0]*$point[0] + $rotationMatrix[1]*$point[1] + $rotationMatrix[2]*$point[2];
    $returnMatrix[1] = $rotationMatrix[3]*$point[0] + $rotationMatrix[4]*$point[1] + $rotationMatrix[4]*$point[2];
    $returnMatrix[2] = $rotationMatrix[6]*$point[0] + $rotationMatrix[7]*$point[1] + $rotationMatrix[8]*$point[2];
    return $returnMatrix;
}
```

I ran this code on an obj file which I tried to rotate by 270 degrees and wrote it out to another file.

When I got the two models side by side in blender they were only 10 degrees apart.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried defining your transformation matrix like this: Rx(α) = [cos(α), -sin(α), 0, sin(α), cos(α), 0, 0, 0, 1] instead?

Comment: That would rotate about the z axis then? I'm positive it has to be rotated around the x!